# CSS Div Being Pushed Down

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I've been working on my first child theme for WordPress for a couple of days and have pretty much got everything working as expected apart from one thing.

```
[http://stevefleming.co.uk/blog/][1]
```

I've tested in Fire Fox and Chrome and the right hand 'widget' div is being pushed 
below. It's not happening on other pages and yes, I did customize the page. I've looked at a working one and then this page and can't see any obvious difference.

Hope somebody can help before I lose my mind.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `#sidebar` before your `#main` in the markup, so that its float affects the main section.

```
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<!-- /#sidebar -->

<div id="main">
</div>
<!-- /#main -->
```

Comment: You might also want to look into the z-indexing of your breadcrumbs and RSS feed stuff. It's hidden underneath your lemons.

Comment: thanks for the response. That fixed it up nicely. I'll look at the z-indexing issue. Why is that important to have those above the lemons? Just curious. And why do the other pages work ok but not this one? Maybe something in the divs that proceeded sidebar were having some kind of knock-on effect... just a guess...

Comment: So you're able to click them :P and I'm not sure about your other pages. I didn't actually look at them before you changed stuff.

Comment: I thought as much on the clicking thing ;) the other pages haven't changed as far as the sidebar is concerned. They all have the sidebar below the main and seem to work fine. Just curious to know what was causing the issue in the blog page.

Answer (score 0):

Add "float: left" to your main so that it should look like:

```
#main {
width: 620px;
float: left;
}
```